# How to calculate total sales per client? Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a column that displays the total sales per 'ClientId'.
A customer can appear several times in my dataset, therefore I want the `TotalSales` value in the new column to be the same constantly for each client.

I tried to do a group by 2 different ways but the output is incorrect, I'm an not sure why, it should be a straightforward calculation
Here is **what I tried:**

```
df['TotalSales'] = df.groupby('ClientId')['Sales'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int) / x.astype(int).sum())
```

```
df['TotalSales'] = df.groupby('ClientId')['Sales'].sum().reset_index()
```

**Sample dataset**

```
dataset = {'ClientId': [10,20,20,20,10,5,3,7,5,20,12,5,3,20,5,8,10,9,7,20,21,5,3,10],
           'Sales': [100,50,25,30,40,50,200,600,20,40,100,20,50,400,250,300,125,75,90,10,225,550,450,55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
```

Does someone know how I may solve this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `df['TotalSales'] = df.groupby('ClientId')['Sales'].transform('sum')`.

Comment: Killi, you are grouping, therefore your output nr of rows won't match the nr of rows of the dataframe df.

Comment: And by the way, if you want the mean you can do this: series = df.groupby('ClientId')['Sales'].apply(np.mean)  and --> import numpy as np

Comment: Ah, that's why! Thank you! I didn't know about ```transform```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['TotalSales'] = df['Sales'].groupby(df['ClientId']).transform('sum')
```